# Post Form with object collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, form-submit

I need to upload Form, which contains several select lists of the same type.

The form look like this

[image]

**View**

```
<form asp-action="UpdateFilter" asp-controller="Home" method="post">

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FilterRows.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px">

                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            @for (int i2 = 0; i2 < Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOptions.Count(); i2++)
                            {
                                <option name="FilterRows[@i].FilterOptions[@i2]"
                                        value="@Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOptions.ToArray()[i2].Value">@Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOptions.ToArray()[i2].Text</option>
                            }
                        </select>

                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-left: 5px">
                            @for (int i3 = 0; i3 < Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOperators.Count(); i3++)
                            {
                                <option name="FilterRows[@i].FilterOperators[@i3]"
                                        value="@Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOperators.ToArray()[i3].Value">@Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOperators.ToArray()[i3].Text</option>
                            }
                        </select>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-left: 5px" />
                    </div>
                }

                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-top: 15px;">Apply</button>
            </form>
```

**Html output**

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/UpdateFilter">

    <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px">

        <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOptions[0]" value=""></option>
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOptions[1]" value="1">Column 1</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOptions[2]" value="2">Column 2</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOptions[3]" value="3">Column 3</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOptions[4]" value="4">Column 4</option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-left: 5px">
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOperators[0]" value=""></option>
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOperators[1]" value="1">Like</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOperators[2]" value="2">&gt;</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOperators[3]" value="3">=</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[0].FilterOperators[4]" value="4">&lt;</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-left: 5px">
    </div>


    <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px">

        <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOptions[0].Value" value=""></option>
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOptions[1].Value" value="1">Column 1</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOptions[2].Value" value="2">Column 2</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOptions[3].Value" value="3">Column 3</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOptions[4].Value" value="4">Column 4</option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-left: 5px">
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOperators[0].Text" value=""></option>
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOperators[1].Text" value="1">Like</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOperators[2].Text" value="2">&gt;</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOperators[3].Text" value="3">=</option>
            <option name="FilterRows[1].FilterOperators[4].Text" value="4">&lt;</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-left: 5px">
    </div>


    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-top: 15px;">Apply</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UpdateFilter(ModalFilterViewModel model)
        {
            return Json(new { success = 1 });
        }
```

ViewModel

```
public class ModalFilterViewModel
    {
        public IList<FilterRow> FilterRows { get; set; }
    }

public class FilterRow
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        public SelectList FilterOptions { get; set; }
        public int? FilterOptionId { get; set; }

        public SelectList FilterOperators { get; set; }
        public int? FilterOperatorId { get; set; }

        public string SearchValue { get; set; }
    }
```

The issue is, that after form submit (apply button hit) the uploaded ViewModel is empty. Why is that and how can i fix it ?

[image]

Comment: in which action you are submitting the form ?? in Apply button click ?can you make the button type as submit ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV yes, i tried to change the `button` tag with `<input type="submit" value="Apply"/>` but the behavior is the same. `<button type='submit'` is the same also.

Comment: can we see the @Model you include in your client side

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV In debug mode, i can treeview the model, but i dont see any export function ?

Comment: I am taking about the view model which you have included in the cshtml file. is it same as ModalFilterViewModel  ?

Comment: Yes, the reference is good. It is the same object.

Comment: can you install filddler and check whether the data is passing or not ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV the HTML is build based on that model, so the input model is OK. The issue is when i submit the form. The data are not posted, the output model is null.

Comment: @GauravMoolani when i first display the page, i dont have selected value yet.

Comment: there are two possibilities 1 - data is not posting at all 2- data is posting but model binder fail to bind it.

Comment: add formcollection and check if any values are really getting posted ?  `JsonResult UpdateFilter(ModalFilterViewModel model ,FormCollection allPostedAalues)`

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV it seems that data are not posted at all, because FormData in request header contains only `RequestVerificationToken`.

Comment: ok so the issue resides in client side only . can you use the mvc form submission syntax instead of this ? like  @using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post)){your code}

Comment: @Guarav Moolani: `FormCollection` contains only verification token but not the data.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV i tried the Html helper, but behavior is the same.

Comment: It is working now ! i will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake was, that i assign the `name` attribute into `option` tag and not to `select` tag. Therefore data was not sent into controller action. Finally i end up with this solution.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="UpdateFilter" method="POST">

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FilterRows.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-inline" style="margin-top:5px">

                        <input type="hidden" name="FilterRows[@i].Id" value="@i" />

                        <select asp-for="@Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOptionId"
                                asp-items="@Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOptions"
                                class="form-control form-control-sm"></select>

                        <select asp-for="@Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOperatorId"
                                asp-items="@Model.FilterRows[i].FilterOperators"
                                class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                style="margin-left: 5px"></select>

                        <input type="text" 
                                asp-for="@Model.FilterRows[i].SearchValue" 
                                class="form-control form-control-sm" 
                                style="margin-left: 5px" />
                    </div>
                }

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-top: 15px;">Apply</button>

            </form>
```